# Guess the poem!

Tags: riddle, knowledge

The world suspends like puppets on a string

When I look away, the strings are

cut

It's like they're playing a game, because

every time I try to see them,

whenever I turn back around,

the world seems to pick up again.

Hint:

> Are you a… raven? I should have loved a thunderbird instead.

Comment: The title and hint make me think of Edgar Allan Poe's "Raven", but I can't see how this fits the riddle itself

Comment: Yeah, the hint itself and the title combined are a bit misleading when you don't take them into context with the rest of the poem. Sorry… It's my second riddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is clearly a reference to

> Mad Girl's Love Song, by Sylvia Plath

Furthermore

> Plath has been noted for interchanging "ravens" with "rooks". While both are part of the crow family, rooks are not found in North America.

Now for wild conjecturing:

> One species of bird that has been described as "suspended like puppets on a string" are finches.

And

> Annie Finch is a contemporary poet and a known fan of Plath's work. Her favorite poem of Plath's is the following:

So maybe the answer is

> Winter Landscape, with Rooks, by Sylvia Plath